# PHP resize image before uploading

Tags: javascript, php, image, dropzone.js

I am building a website where the admin should be able to upload images. If the image is larger than 2MB it will fail because of the limit. But even if there was no limit it would still be better to resize the image because of loading times for visitors.

An image should never be wider than 800px, the height doesn't matter because it will never be large.
What I now want to do is resize the image so the width is 800px or lower and the height is resized by the same ratio.

What I have now is the following:

```
if (!empty($_FILES)) 
{
    $upload_dir = 'photos';
    $tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

    $targetPath = dirname( __FILE__ ) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $upload_dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
    $mainFile = $targetPath . time() . '-' . $_FILES['file']['name'];

    list($w, $h) = getimagesize($tempFile);
    if ($w > 800) 
    {   
        $ratio = 800 / $w;
        $newHeight = $ratio * $h;

        $tempFile = imagescale($tempFile, 800);
    }

    move_uploaded_file($tempFile, $mainFile);
}
```

but this doesn't do anything.

I am using dropzone with this script as the target for the image input.

Can someone point me in the right direction?
Or has PHP already tried to upload the image once it is in `$_FILES`? If that is the case, I don't know how to solve it. Then it should be resized *before* dropzone calls this script.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have $_FILES you image is already on the server. You can resize it client-side in HTML5 using the canvas element.

Try to read this:

https://hacks.mozilla.org/2011/01/how-to-develop-a-html5-image-uploader/

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using [WideImage](http://wideimage.sourceforge.net/). You can then use `resize()` like this:

```
WideImage::load('big.png')->resize(50, 30)->saveToFile('small.jpg');
```